# How to use _.over, over two variables?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

This is the jist of what I'm trying to get to work. At this point it's feeling like not using _.over functions would be easier

```
(value, key) => _.overSome(thingOnValueA, thingOnValueB, thingOnKeyA)
```

`_.oversome` creates a function that checks all predicates, and in my real example I have about 5 predicates. The problem is that it's passing both variables in an array to all the inner functions/predicates, when the first two should be on value and the last one on the key. I've tried this, but it did not work:

```
(value, key) => _.overSome(thingOnValueA(value), thingOnValueB(value), thingOnKeyA(key))
```

(overSome requires functions, not funciton calls)

and also:

```
(value, key) => _.overSome(value => thingOnValueA(value), value => thingOnValueB(value), key =>thingOnKeyA(key))
```

(eslint warns that value is already in use in the upper scope)

[user3297291](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431795/how-to-use-over-over-two-variables?noredirect=1#comment77826468_45431795) suggested this:

```
(value, key) => _.overSome(() => thingOnValueA(value), () => thingOnValueB(value), () =>thingOnKeyA(key))
```

which transpiles to

```
var myFunction = function myFunction(value, key) {
    return _.overSome(function() {
        return thingOnValueA(value)
    }, function() {
        return thingOnValueb(value)
    }, function() {
        return thingOnKeyA(key)
    }, 
}
```

I think because of how lodash works, when it runs each function, it looks at the arguments passed to it, and gets 0, which breaks how this works.

My situation, for context is that I'm checking an array or key-value pairs to see if they're valid search terms

```
[
    {shoeSize: 5},
    {colour: "white"}
    {width: ""}
    {searchId: "8dc0ce98-5b72-4993-bbe3-6edc1ec2a5b8"}
 ]
```

So I'm excluding invalid colours, empty strings and shoe sizes that are too big and fields I'm not actually interested in(this is just a dummy example, I'm not selling shoes!).

How do I split the `_.overSome` function betweeen two variables?

edit:

Here is a concrete example of what I'm doing:

```
const hasInternalField = _.partial(_.includes, ['searchId']);
const isInvalidSearchTerm = _.overSome(_.isundefined, _.isEmpty, _.negate(_.isString), hasInternalField)
```

For now I'm taking `hasInternalField` out of the `_.overSome` and checking when isInvalidSearchTerm is called. I'm still interested in an actual solution.

Comment: Not sure if it's pretty, but I think this should work: `(value, key) => _.overSome(() => thingOnValueA(value), () => thingOnValueB(value), () =>thingOnKeyA(key))` (`value` and `key` now refer to the initially passed ones, instead of new arguments).

Comment: @user3297291 I think because of how lodash expects `overSome` to pick up arguments, passing it a function like `() =>thingOnValueA(value)` breaks it. I'll add the transpiled code and what I see when looking over the lodash sourcecode.

Comment: Can you give concrete examples of the predicates and how the function returned by `_.overSome` is used?

Comment: If your predicates don't take multiple arguments you could always bind the value to your predicates: `(value, key) => _.overSome(thingOnValueA.bind(null, value), thingOnValueB.bind(null, value), thingOnKeyA.bind(null, key))`

Comment: I removed the transpiled version of the code, I don't think it's relevant to the question.

Comment: if by any chance you get the data from JSON.parse, it lets you exclude keys from the result https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples

Answer (score 0):

`_.overSome` takes a set of predicate functions as inputs and returns a single function, for example:

```
const g = _.overSome(f1, f2, f3);
```

The inner functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3` will be called with whatever arguments are passed to `g`.  Often `g` is passed a single argument, but it can also take one or zero arguments, as well.

For example, if you wanted to

```
// Zero argument version
const predicate = (value, key) => _.overSome(
     () => thingOnValueA(value),
     () => thingOnValueB(value),
     () => thingOnKeyA(key)
)(); // Don't forget to actually call the function returned by `_.overSome`
```

(You could also partially apply the filter functions, e.g. replace `() => thingOnValueA(value)` with `thingOnValueA.bind(null, value)`, or `_.partial(thingOnValueA, value)`, but personally I think the arrow function version is cleaner)

---

Alternatively, you could pass `value` and `key` directly to the function returned by `_.overSome` and eliminate the extra function wrapper:

```
// Two argument version
const predicate = _.overSome(
    (value, key) => thingOnValueA(value),
    (value, key) => thingOnValueB(value),
    (value, key) => thingOnKeyA(key),
);
```